# JQuery fetches only first value from radiobutton

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_report_type" value="customerinvoice" required>
    <label for="">Customer Invoice</label>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_report_type" value="packinglist">
    <label for="">Packing List</label>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_report_type" value="performainvoice">
    <label for="">Performa Invoice</label>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_report_type" value="commercialinvoice">
    <label for="">Commercial Invoice</label>    
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_productformat" value="description">
    <label for="">Description</label>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_productformat" value="picture">
    <label for="">Picture</label>
    <input type="radio" name="erp_productformat" value="descriptionpicture">
    <label for="">Description &amp; Picture</label>
</div>
```

i want to fetch the value from `erp_productformat` based on `erp_report_type` change event. this is the jQuery i am using for it.

```
$("input[name='erp_report_type']").change(function() {
    var type = $(this).val();
    var productFormat = $("input[name='erp_productformat']").val(); 
    if( type == 'customerinvoice') {

    } else if(type == 'packinglist') {

    } else if(type == 'performainvoice') {

    } else if(type == 'commercialinvoice') {

    }
});
```

the problem is variable productFormat will hold only the first value i.e `description` it does not fetch the other value if i check the other two field.

i am still a noob to jQuery or JS. where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
var productFormat = $("input[name='erp_productformat']").filter(':checked').val();
```

This will return the checked value from 'erp_productformat' group of inputs and then it's value.

Comment: i need :checked :), i did it once and i forgot it :D

Comment: i don't think you even need filter for this. this is what i did var `productFormat = $("input[name='erp_productformat']:checked").val();`

Comment: You don't need `.filter()`; you're right. However, I can never remember if you need a space before `:checked` or not if you put it in the selector. I wanted to give you something I knew worked, rather than an incomplete solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$("input[name='erp_productformat']").each(function(){
    var productFormat = $(this).val()
    if( type == 'customerinvoice') {
    } else if(type == 'packinglist') {
    } else if(type == 'performainvoice') {
    } else if(type == 'commercialinvoice') {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
each(function() {
```

instead of

```
change(function() {
```

Comment: bad idea, i want my code to be executed using onchange event, not everything.